# Prerferred way of specifying configuration options for a custom AngularJS element

Tags: angularjs

When creating widgets in AngularJS, usually you'll need to have a means of specifying configuration options for the widget. Here is one custom AngularJS element:

```
<typeahead items="items" prompt="Start typing a US state" title="name" subtitle="abbreviation" model="name" on-select="onItemSelected()" />
```

and this is the directive:

```
typeAhead.directive('typeahead', function ($timeout)
{
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    scope: {
      items: '=',
      prompt: '@',
      title: '@',
      subtitle: '@',
      model: '=',
      onSelect: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs)
    {
    },
    templateUrl: 'templates/templateurl.html'
  }
});
```

It does seem somewhat silly to have to specify all your configuration options as isolated scope members. I think I saw somewhere configuration stuff done something like this instead:

```
<typeahead items="items" options="{'prompt': 'enter a name', 'title': 'States'} />
```

What would be the preferred way of handling options?

Comment: Look at ng-grid documentation. It uses a gridOptions configuration object for managing configuration. You can try to create a single object for your configuration too.

Comment: This seems to be a good solution. It allows you to configure a widget with settings that could be retrieved from a server as opposed to hard coding them in the custom element as shown in my html above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For readOnly options passed to a directive, this is a fairly simple and clean way of doing it:

```
app.directive('directive', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      options: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.options = scope.options();
    }
  }
});
```

Then in your calling markup / controller (w/e), you can specify it as such:

```
app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.dirOpts = { optionOne: 'valueOne', optionTwo: 'valueTwo', .... };
});

<div directive options="dirOpts"></div>
```

You could ofcourse replace the `&` with an `=` in the directive definition if you want two-way binding for the options object passed to the directive, but then we're talking values and not necessarily configuration options, config options should be readOnly and two-way binding needs should be covered by standalone values (imo).

I've tried to emulate the behaviour of the ngGridOptions to function with an isolated scope, but that is on a whole other level of nutcracking (for me, anyways).

If you're using `scope: true`, the ngGridOptions example is spot on.

If you're using `scope: {}`, I'm at a loss on how to pass a structure similar to what you've supplied without reverse engineering the registration of properties on the isolated scope and the passing of values between the directive callee scope and the isolated one.

Comment: I don't think setting options for a directive in the controller is a good thing. The optiions need to be setup within the directive. The controller should be ignorant of what directives are used as well as their configuration options. But that is just my opinion. Still that does seem to be the AngularJS way of separating controllers and views.

Comment: If defining your local options for the directive in the calling context (controller, some other directive, some markup) is a problem, then I'd suggest you take a peak at having a service with predefined option configurations that you may call from the directive based on some parameter passed into the directive. I hope that makes a little bit of sense, but it's really just separating the configuration further away from the directive itself.